# HTTP Post in objective-c doesn't post anything

Tags: php, objective-c, http

I have the code below which runs fine but doesn't appear to post anything, or at least my php doesn't pick it up. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my php:

```
$usr = $_POST['username'];
$psw = $_POST['password'];
if ($usr == '1' && $psw == '1') {
    echo 'Yes';
}
```

And here's my objective-c

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://ep.samico.dk/blogapp/login.php?";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"You are authorized"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertsuccess show];

} else {
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fail" message:@"Invalid Access"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertsuccess show];

}
```

Comment: Change the response to just `print_r($_POST);` and see what it returns.

Comment: I'm guessing you're actually formatting a GET request rather than post.

Comment: Or `var_dump($_POST);` tomato - tomahto.

Comment: Paul Bain is correct; what you're doing will put the nominated parameters directly into the URL, so you end up issuing a GET. The PHP appears to be creating a POST?

Comment: When i change the response to var_dump($_POST); the output is: php[3413:f803] array(0) {
}

Comment: Well, if i change the php variables to $_GET.. it returns the values

Comment: @EmilBüchlerSeierPetersen that var_dump output indicates that *NO* data was submitted via the POST method. If you try `var_dump($_GET);` I expect you'll see your variables ... in which case you need to either change `$_POST` to `$_GET` in your PHP code or use objective-c to submit a POST request instead of a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Going off what was said in the comments:

The below section (your code) generates the URL string with the parameters added to the end of it.

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://ep.samico.dk/blogapp/login.php?";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
```

You can either modify this to actually do a POST *or* you can modify your PHP code to handle them as a GET instead of a POST.

```
$usr = $_GET['username'];
$psw = $_GET['password'];
if ($usr == '1' && $psw == '1') {
    echo 'Yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a POST in objc, you need to use `NSURLConnection` directly, like the following:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", @"username", @"pass"];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://ep.samico.dk/blogapp/login.php?";
NSURL *hostURL = [NSURL URLWithString:hostStr];
NSMutableURLRequest *req  = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:hostURL];
[req setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```